# How to count the occurrence from a foreach loop in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

From a foreach loop ,suppose  i am getting data in this way and piping into a custom object how can i count the values inside it..

> Alpha  |  Count
>
> --------   ----------
>
> A   | Exists
>
> A    | Exists
>
> A  |  Exists
>
> B  | Not- Exists
>
> B | Not-Exists

I need in this way

> Alpha  |  Count
>
> --------   ----------
>
> A | 3
>
> B | 2

Comment: As in your example,my data is not static .It is continuously iterating to the array.
Can you suggest how can we count?

Answer (score 3):

The [Group-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) cmdlet sounds like it will suit your needs perfectly.

Example:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem | Group-Object extension -NoElement
Count Name
----- ----
21
82   .txt
9    .cmd
5    .log
12   .xml
5    .htm
36   .ps1
1    .psc1
3    .exe
6    .csv
1    .psd1
2    .bat
```